# Can't query SQLite file located in read only directory

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a directory that contains the following files:

```
contacts.sqlite
forms.sqlite
locations.sqlite
locations.sqlite-shm
locations.sqlite-wal
```

I only have the following NTFS permissions on this directory:

- Read & execute
- List folder contents
- Read

When I'm trying to query those files with Java JDBC I'm getting different behavior:

- **contacts.sqlite**: Exception - [SQLITE_CANTOPEN]  Unable to open the database file (unable to open database file)
- **forms.sqlite**: I can query data successfully.
- **locations.sqlite**: Expcetion - [SQLITE_IOERR_SHMOPEN]  I/O error within xShmMap while trying to open a new shared memory segment (disk I/O error)

Here are some notes:

- There is only one database connection per file.
- The application that is using those files is closed/crashed.
- I can't delete or change files in original directory
- I can't change directory permission.
- I just need to query data, no need to insert any data.
- I tried to open those files with "DB Browser for SQLite" and I can only open "forms.sqlite" which is same case as Java JDBC.

I tried the following:

- Copy files to directory with read/write permission and I was able to query them all.
- Set journal_mode to OFF: didn't help
- Set temp_store to memory: didn't help
- Open DB as read only: didn't help

Edit:
I'm using Xerial SQLite JDBC driver. I tried to open as read only and setting other paragma as following:

```
SQLiteConfig  config = new SQLiteConfig();
config.setPragma(Pragma.JOURNAL_MODE, "OFF");
//config.setOpenMode(SQLiteOpenMode.READONLY);
config.setReadOnly(true);
DriverManager.getConnection("data_base_url",
                    config.toProperties());
```

My question: is there a way to query those files while they are located in original directory without changing its permission?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `mode=ro` option to your connection string (ref: [here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html))?

Comment: @GordThompson yes I tried it and it didn't help, I updated my question.

Comment: Do you want to open the databases in-place because other applications will be updating them and you want to see the changes in real time?

Comment: Not really, no application will update those files. The application that used those files is either closed/crashed.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](http://pastebin.com/iGzKze9b) might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, but still not working and I'm still getting same behavior. The thing that is confusing me: I can understand why it's not able to open "locations.sqlite" because there is "locations.sqlite-shm" and "locations.sqlite-wal", but I can't understand why it's not able to open "contacts.sqlite"

Comment: Sorry for the false lead re: using `:resource:` in the URL. I thought that the "DB files will be extracted to a temporary folder" as stated [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/wiki/Usage), but that appears not to be the case for `file://` resources. You'll probably have to do the copying yourself, as in [this example](http://pastebin.com/YCmGwyD4). As for not being able to open "contacts.sqlite", it may simply be a WAL database that was shut down properly. (The lingering "-shm" and "-wal" files for the "locations" database suggest that it may not have enjoyed an orderly shutdown.)

Comment: Thanks so much Gord. I had this idea to copy db files to temp folder where I have write permission. However, I was trying to find better solution as the db files can get really big and this may slow things down. but it seems like this is the only solution. thanks again :)

Comment: If you copy "contacts.sqlite" to a read/write folder and open it there do you see "-shm" and "-wal" files getting created?

Comment: sorry for late replay, had health issue. No, it doesn't create those files. They way I tested it is by creating a new connection, query database and doing Thread.wait()

Answer (score 0):

As documented in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/wal.html), databases in WAL mode must be opened with write access.

You have to change to rollback journal mode, or use a writable directory.

Comment: I changed journal mode to rollback by setting "PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE", but I'm still getting same behavior.

Comment: Did that change succeed?

Comment: executing "pragma journal_mode" returns "delete"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I had and error "Unable to open the database file" while trying to open the SQLite DB in ReadOnly mode, which was stored in folder with "Read, Read execute" permissions.
Solution were simple, turned out that file has "File format write version" (offset:0x12) and "File format read version" (offset:0x13) fields inside.
In both I had value "0x02" which means WAL (see [file format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)). You need to have 0x01 there (Legacy) in case you want to be able to access DB in read-only directory.

**Solution**:
Copy DB file to some ReadWrite folder and use any hex-editor to update DB file. And sure you mustn't use WAL JournalMode in future when connecting to DB.
Also in case you have *.sqlite-shm and *.sqlite-wal - this files must disappear after all clients are disconnected from DB, so seems DB files were copied while active connection.